# SENDTO sends packet, but sniffer does not see it

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp

I have the UDP connection between 2 Linux machines. Once in about 40-50ms side A sends a numbered request and waits for the reply from the side B.
Nothing can be sent till the reply arrives, excluding the timeout which is 2s.
It takes about 10-15ms for B to prepare the reply and send it.
The connection is point-to-point.

The problem is that once in 300-400 exchanges the side A does not receive any reply from B.

For the test and investigation purposes, I connected everything to a hub and run wireshark on PC connected.
What I see is that when the side A does not see the reply, wireshark also does not see it.
Yet, side B thinks that the packet was sent, because the log print, which resides exactly after the sendto(...) always prints the "lost" packet number.

The question is: what may be the cause of the packet been lost on its way from the application (sendto(...)) to the wire.
Taking into account that there is absolutely no load - CPU is 95% free on the B side and the link is point-to-point.

Comment: What is your question? Whether a packet can get lost in an Ethernet network? Yes, it can. What to do with this? Use timeouts, retransmissions, and methods like those (hint: read how TCP works).

Comment: agree with above poster. also, you might get more interest in your question if you don't start with "UDP connection between 2 Linux machines"... UDP is connectionless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to rodolk for the hint. Don't know why I did not do this earlier...:)

The wireshark printout will not be useful, as it simply does not show the lost packet - nothing to investigate.

The sendto is clean, no errors too.
But this gave me the hint to look at the interface statistics:
cat /proc/net/dev
From now on everything was very simple - the 'coll' counter was exactly the same as the number of lost reply packages.

Obviously some hardware problem.

Thanks a lot to community for the help.

Comment: "Obviously some hardware problem." Actually, it's a network problem. If you're using modern Ethernet equipment, all links should be handled by switches, running full-duplex links. In a full-duplex switched network you should never see collisions. So it might be the lack of a switched network (in 2013? oh no), or the lack of proper auto-negotiation, leading to half-duplex links.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is not reliable. It's probable the datagram was lost before reaching A.

Can you share the wireshark file for Wireshark running on B? Probably you will see the lost datagram there. Other possibilities:
-You have a buffer overflow and breaking something in the sent data. 
-sendto is receiving an error when sending the lost datagram. Are you checking return code less than 0 and errno?

But without the wireshark file it's difficult to guess. Sharing the code is also helpful.